# what would the word "is" mean in an algorithm in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an algorithm I have to put into code and I'm not sure what exactly "is" means.. How would I translate:

```
if (inFile1 is EOF)
```

would it be

```
if (inFile1 = EOF)
```

Does "is" translate to "="?

Comment: If you have questions like this then start reading a quickstarter C/C++ tutorial before trying to solve any kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `==` operator, it checks if two values are equals, or if one *is* the other:

```
if (inFile1 == EOF)
```

Comment: Hmmm, still not sure why you would check if a file (stream maybe?) is `EOF`, however... I don't think that will work, maybe an `isEOF` method was wanted?